# Execute javascript code in Remix IDE?

Tags: remix

I noticed that the remix IDE now says that I can run Javascript code from .js file. I can't find any documentation. Is this possible? How do you do this?

Thanks!

Comment: In the log console it show a few lines of help when you load remix. Try `remix.help()` in that console to display it again.